# Node Mysql Escaping - Mysql.Escape() / Mysql.EscapeId()

Tags: node.js, node-mysql, mysqljs

I am using mysql-node: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql but I am a little confused about default sanitization, `Mysql.Escape()` vs `Mysql.EscapeId()` and the use of `?` vs `??`. The docs says?

**Default Sanitization**

> When you pass an Object to .escape() or .query(), .escapeId() is used
>   to avoid SQL injection in object keys.

I see the term Object, so does that mean I should still escape queries like this?

`UPDATE table SET  updated_at = userInput WHERE name = userInput`.

**Mysql.Escape() vs Mysql.EscapeId()** 
What is the difference between these two functions. The docs says mysql.escape uses mysql.escapeId. I know they both sanitize input but is there a case where you use one or the other?

**? vs ??** 
The docs use `?` and `??` interchangeably. Do they mean the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I talked to the maintainer of mysqljs and confirmed that this package doesn't escape queries by default.

> When you pass an Object to .escape() or .query(), .escapeId() is used
>   to avoid SQL injection in object keys.

The statement above means queries will be escaped if you use one of the following methods.

```
let args = { name: 'myname' otherVals: 'blah blah'}; 
mysql.query('Insert INTO table SET ?',args);

let name = 'test'; 
mysql.query('INSERT INTO table SET name = ?', [name]);
```

For the second part of the questions: `??` and `escapeId` is used for identifiers and `?` and `escape()` is used for values.

Comment: The 'insert into table set ?' is such a great tip that it should be in the node-mysql examples.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation describes what escape() and escapeId() do. Use escape() when you need to escape values. Use escapeId() when you need to escape identifiers (e.g., table, database, or column names).